# UE5 - Actors with physics and collisions enabled going through the floor despite having CCD

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

Since I've ported my project from UE4.27 to UE5 I've had this bug on every actor that has Simulate Physics enabled.

I have a mechanic where the player can grab an object and then throw it to the floor. This worked perfectly on UE4.27, but **on UE5 the actor will go through the floor most of the time.**
**The floor is a plane made with mesh tools and has a collision**. I'm wondering if there's any way to fix this issue without manually adding an invisible collission beneath every floor (which it looks like it has worked so far, but it would take a lot of time because my game has a very big world with tons of different floors and floor levels).

Here are some videos of what happens when a player throws an object to the floor:
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJBtY.jpg**

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQaIo.jpg**

Comment: Hey, your question is missing a crutial info about the setup of collision/physic on affected objects. Without this it might be really hard to find an answear. Please specify post by providing reproduction or more general info about the issue.

Comment: There can be a few things wrong: 1. assets have collision but no proper preset (mask) preventing them from clipping; 2. 'TraceComplexOnMove' is set or not on affected assets (this actually can create behaviour that you've described when setted up in wrong way https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Physics/SimpleVsComplex/); 3. There might be something in code itself that affects how collision/physic works; Anyway this issue seems to be often when using Unreal https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/objects-fall-through-the-floor/25180 It can be caused by a lot of things

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn on "constant collision detection" or "ccd" on your mesh.